# How to pas params as bytes on solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have two functions on contract:

function 1 receives `bytes params` variable

`function foo1(bytes memory params)`

function 2 receives two params: `address param1, uint256 param2`

`function foo2(address param1, uint256 param2)`

my goals somehow pass params as bytes to `foo1`, decode it on function, and pass decoded params to `foo2`

like:

```
function foo2(address param1, uint256 param2) {
   // do something
}

function decode(bytes params) private returns(???){
  // decode
}

function foo1(bytes params) public {
  var decodedParams = fromBytes(params)
  foo2(decodedParams.param1, decodedParams.param2)
}
```

from frontend I expect something like:

```
  const params = toBytes({param1: '0xAddRess', param2: 1})

  myContract.foo1(params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [abi.encodeParameters()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameters) on frontend

```
const bytesHex = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
    ['address', 'uint256'],
    ['0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe', '1']
);
```

and [abi.decode()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/cheatsheet.html#global-variables) in the contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function foo2(address param1, uint256 param2) external {
        // do something
    }
    
    function foo1(bytes memory params) external {
        (address decodedAddress, uint256 decodedUint) = abi.decode(params, (address, uint256));
        this.foo2(decodedAddress, decodedUint);
    }
}
```